# PCA to identify patterns in the data, forced to a particular variable?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, pattern-recognition, stepwise-regression, spectral-analysis

**Dataset:** I have a hyperspectral dataset that consists 250 wavelength bands (x1,...x250) and corresponding reflectance measurements (y) for each band. Plotting X vs Y yields a spectral profile. I have a sample of n = 30 spectral profiles, each associated with a unique value Z (age). -- see attached images for spectral profiles, and PC1 results.

**Goal:** I am trying to predict Z from characteristic patterns of the spectral profile. I am looking to identify patterns of variance (of the entire spectrum) that correspond with Z.

**Attempts**: I have run PCA to identify patterns of variance on the dataset, and created loading plots of the PCs vs Z. There is some success in PC1, but I believe variance patterns that correlate with Z are mixed between different PCs. **Is there a way to force PCA to identify patterns of variance in the dataset that correspond specifically with Z**.

I am open to other statistical methods. I have tried MLR & stepwise regression with some success, but I am really looking for the overall pattern from X1...X250 that corresponds with Z, not just discrete X variables. Thanks!

[image]
[image]